# AudioJS - Stop playing with javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, audio

I have a problem with audiojs: Im building a website where you can hear 3 or more sound examples. The audiojs player works perfectly, but I have one big problem:

I have the audiojs-players (3) in twitter bootstrap accordion-panels. That means, when you click on one panel, it will open and show you the player and you can start to play the audio. But I want the song stop playing, when I choose another panel (The selected panel closes when I choose another one)

### This is what I already have:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                             $('#myCollapsible').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
                                 function(event){ sound.pause();
sound.currentTime = 0;();

})
                         </script>
```

Sorry for my bad english, I'm german. And thanks for every answer!

Comment: You are indeed correct. The real question is however why to waste an entire question instead of writing 4 lines of code and trying it out :D

Comment: But I don't have any knowledge about javascript... Could you please help me if its so easy? :D

Comment: This is the moment I have another almost stock comment. 
Stackoverflow is a Q&A site meant to help programmers solve issues with their programming, or other issues that come up with programming. Not a do my work for me site. If you want to hire a programmer there are other sites which google can no doubt find for you.

Comment: Yes I know, I just asked for help man...

Comment: No problem and no harsh feelings, everyone has to learn sometime. Also this question as it stands doesn't offer enough details for anyone to implement the solution you're asking for either.

Answer (score 1):

This could give you an idea on how to start

You don't need "to send a signal" when clicking on another panel. Just do your stuff when collapsing the panel which contains the player.

```
$('#myCollapsible').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
  // do something…
})
```

Comment: Hmm I didn't know there was a signal emitted on that. Damn nice for future reference :)

Comment: Yep. There are four events that can be fired when toggling a collapsible element to shown or hidden. You can learn more about them [**here**](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-usage)